# Getting the offsets of a list of elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of headers that I wish to convert into a list of their offsets from the top. Can someone tell me why the following code doesn't work?

```
var headers = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').filter(function() {
  // get all headers with an ID
  return this.id;
})

console.log($(headers).map(function() { 
    this.offsetTop;
}))
```

I'm not very experienced in using jquery, so my apologies that this is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has an `offset()` method

```
var offsetArr = $.map($('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').filter('[id]'), function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().top;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KgYc/)